# Html beautifier throws the following "Outdented too far on line" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, code-formatting

I have installed html beautifier gem. When I beautify some files the following errors are thrown. Not for all the files.

$ htmlbeautifier **abc.html.erb**

```
/home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:9:in `rescue in beautify': Error parsing abc.html.erb: Outdented too far on line 163 (RuntimeError)
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:6:in `beautify'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:16:in `open'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:13:in `each'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/gems/htmlbeautifier-0.0.8/bin/htmlbeautifier:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/bin/htmlbeautifier:23:in `load'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/bin/htmlbeautifier:23:in `<main>'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@a/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@aer-ui/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Here is my ruby

**$ whereis ruby**

```
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/lib/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby1.8 /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
```

What the error is? how it could be solved??

Answer (score 1):

The source code of [htmlbeautifier](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier/blob/master/lib/htmlbeautifier/builder.rb) suggests that in your files you have mismatched closing `end` keyword or `}` closing brace.

It would help more if you have enclosed one of you html files.

Comment: ya its correct. I am unabale to beautify the  biggest files. I dont have permission to show my codes. Sorry friend. Cant I implement it??

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by implement it?
You can although share a link to some plunker, jsbin or other with this file.

Comment: Sry. I mean cant i do it with htmlbeautifier??

Comment: It seems that htmlbeautifier works correctly. It can't work with missmatched braces or end statements. You need to correct those html.erb files (find where you have put an extra ruby `end` keyword or an extra closing brace `}`)

Comment: Merstzik:                                                      $rails-erb-check _abc.html.erb
_abc.html.erb => valid.                                            I ve tested the file with a gem called rails-erb-check. It show me the file is a valid one. I have beautified a valid file. Eventhough the above error is thrown. So I feel it would not be the issue